# Creating a mysql view using php artisan for migration?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How do you create a mysql view using php artisan? Can't find any documentation on it???

Google and Bing aren't returning much at all!

documentation for Laravel: http://laravel.com/docs/migrations

Comment: why do you want to create a view using artisan?

Comment: The migration... Instead of creating a table, I need to create and version control a view. Hope that helps... The negative vote is absolutely shocking... Remove it to make sure I don't facepalm.

Comment: You can run raw queries to do that (in a migration file)

Comment: Cool... that'll do it mate.. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Your question is a little unclear. It **seems** you may not understand the difference between Views, Migrations and MySQL Tables.

Migrations can be created with Artisan via `php artisan make:migration ...` or manually. They contain code that create MySQL Tables.

Views are template files that display a page for end users to interact with. In Laravel, Views are Blade Templates.

Artisan does not offer a command for creating Views. But there are Composer packages you can install that will extend Artisan with such functionality.

- https://github.com/bencomeau/artisan-make-view
- https://github.com/svenluijten/artisan-view

Comment: @spencer-hill :) Thanks for trying. I do appreciate it. Take a look at MySQL views using kirk-beard's link. They are useful tool to get to know for your exploration into programming. Good luck dude.